# Closing jQuery Mobile Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a panel with links like this

> Page1
>   Page2
>   Page3

If I am currently on Page1 and open the panel, the panel is not closed when I select Page1 again. I have checked [jQuery mobile panel documentation](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/panels/), and has the same behaviour (if you open the panel an click on "Panels", the panel will stay open.

Is there a way to close the panel if same page link is selected?

Edit: jQuery Mobile version: 1.3.2
      jQuery version: 1.9.1

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Close it programmatically, `$(".selector").panel("close");`

Comment: here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/k89A5/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do something like this

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
  $("[data-role=panel] a").on("click", function () {
    if($(this).attr("href") == "#"+$.mobile.activePage[0].id) {
      $("[data-role=panel]").panel("close");
    }
  });
});
```

**Update:** For jQM >= 1.4 use `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")` instead of `$.mobile.activePage`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/k89A5/1/

Comment: You can just use the   $("[data-role=panel]").panel("close"); in a return function to close the panel

Answer (score 3):

only add data-rel="close"

```
 <li class="liPanel"><a href="javascript:void(0);" **data-rel="close"** class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-info">Faqs</a>
</li>
```