# jQuery Mobile panel not getting closed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, panel, sidebar

I am having a small issue.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2cwsD/27/) fiddle. I have a sidebar menu on Chapters. Now, I open the sidebar menu and click on Chapter 2, then the menu gets closed and Chapter 2 is opened. Now I again click on Chapter 2 in side bar menu, then the sidebar menu should get closed, but it doesn't.

Here is html code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="Ch1">
    <div>
        <a href="#leftNavmenuCh1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="bars">Chapters</a>

    </div>
    <div id="leftNavmenuCh1" data-role="panel" data-icon='false' data-iconpos="notext" data-position="left" data-display="overlay"
            data-dismissible="true">
        <header class="nav-header">list header</header>
        <ul id="leftMenuCh1" data-role='listview' data-icon='false' class="sidelist"  >
        <li><a href='#Ch1' class='navlink'  >chap 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Ch2' class='navlink'  >chap 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Ch3' class='navlink'  >chap 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role='content'>
        content chapter 1
    </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="Ch2">
    <div>
        <a href="#leftNavmenuCh2" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="bars">Chapters</a>

    </div>
    <div id="leftNavmenuCh2" data-role="panel" data-icon='false' data-iconpos="notext" data-position="left" data-display="overlay"
            data-dismissible="true">
        <header class="nav-header">list header</header>
        <ul id="leftMenuCh2" data-role='listview' data-icon='false' class="sidelist"  >
        <li><a href='#Ch1' class='navlink'  >chap 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Ch2' class='navlink'  >chap 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Ch3' class='navlink'  >chap 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role='content'>
        content chapter 2
    </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="Ch3">
    <div>
        <a href="#leftNavmenuCh3" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="bars">Chapters</a>

    </div>
    <div id="leftNavmenuCh3" data-role="panel" data-icon='false' data-iconpos="notext" data-position="left" data-display="overlay"
            data-dismissible="true">
        <header class="nav-header">list header</header>
        <ul id="leftMenuCh3" data-role='listview' data-icon='false' class="sidelist"  >
            <li><a href='#Ch1' class='navlink'  >chap 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Ch2' class='navlink'  >chap 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Ch3' class='navlink'  >chap 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role='content'>
        content chapter 3
    </div>

</div>
```

Please let me know what I could do in this case.

P.S: I am not able to use any other library for side menu at this stage, as my whole application is fully functional except this small issue and published in stores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually it's a problem for me i could not fix too , but here is a solution for your problem without any library or something :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
  $("[data-role=panel] a").on("click", function () {
    if($(this).attr("href") == "#"+$.mobile.activePage[0].id) {
      $("[data-role=panel]").panel("close");
    }
  });
});
```

which check if the hash of your target is the same like the current one then it close the panel . hope this help .

and here is a live demo :
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cwsD/29/)

you can refer to this post :

[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478094/closing-jquery-mobile-panel)

Comment: I've seen this code before, this is a copy/paste, isn't? ;)

Comment: actually i have the same issue before and i found the answer in this post which you'v answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478094/closing-jquery-mobile-panel  :)

Comment: answer modified and adding the post that you have answered , i only want to help him with the answer not giving him another link to review and i already have this code in one of my projects so i only get it form javascript file and post it in the answer now to find your post i had to search for it again :)