# jQueryMobile 1.3.1 Panels do not work after some transitions with menu

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

jQueryMobile 1.3.1 with Backbone.js

I have recently noticed that after some transitions, the Panels do not work. Other events as onclick on logohead works, but not panels...

This is the menu that is inflated on very page. I fill all slide panels inside ondeviceready:

```
function cargarMenu() {
//Inserta el menú de la aplicación
var text = 
   "<ul data-role='listview' data-divider-theme='h' data-inset='false' data-icon='false' > \
        <li data-role='list-divider' role='heading' id='menu_title' > \
            Wellcome on board Paul \
        </li> \
        <li data-theme='g'> \
            <a href='#HomePage2' data-transition='slide'> \
                <img src='Imagenes/ico_menu_home2.png' class='ui-li-icon'>{0} \
            </a> \
        </li> \
        <li data-theme='g'> \
            <a href='#HomePage' data-transition='slide'> \
                <img src='Imagenes/ico_menu_next.png' class='ui-li-icon'>{1} \
                <span class='ui-li-count' id='timeToNext'> \
                    in 01:45 \
                </span> \
            </a> \
        </li> \
        <li data-theme='g'> \
            <a href='#RecordListPage' data-transition='slide'> \
                <img src='Imagenes/ico_menu_record.png' class='ui-li-icon'>{2} \
            </a> \
        </li> \
        <li data-theme='g'> \
            <a href='#ChartsPage' data-transition='slide'> \
                <img src='Imagenes/ico_menu_chart.png' class='ui-li-icon'>{3} \
            </a> \
        </li> \
        <li id='menu_messages' data-theme='g'> \
            <a href='#MessagesPage' data-transition='slide'> \
                <img src='Imagenes/ico_menu_messages.png' class='ui-li-icon'>{4} \
                <span class='ui-li-count' id='menu_numMsg'> \
                    0 \
                </span> \
            </a> \
        </li> \
        <li id='menu_library' data-theme='g'> \
            <a onclick='app.util.extLibrary()'> \
                <img src='Imagenes/ico_menu_library.png' class='ui-li-icon'>{5} \
            </a> \
        </li> \
        <li id='menu_surveys' data-theme='g'> \
            <a href='#SurveysPage' data-transition='slide'> \
                <img src='Imagenes/ico_menu_surveys.png' class='ui-li-icon'>{6} \
                <span class='ui-li-count' id='menu_numSrv'> \
                    0 \
                </span> \
            </a> \
        </li> \
        <li data-theme='g'> \
            <a href='#MyProfilePage' data-transition='slide'> \
                <img src='Imagenes/ico_menu_profile.png' class='ui-li-icon'>{7} \
            </a> \
        </li> \
        <li data-theme='g'> \
            <a href='#InjectionListPage' data-transition='slide'> \
                <img src='Imagenes/ico_menu_schedule.png' class='ui-li-icon'>{8} \
            </a> \
        </li> \
        <li data-theme='g'> \
            <a href='#SettingsPage' data-transition='slide'> \
                <img src='Imagenes/ico_menu_settings.png' class='ui-li-icon'>{9} \
            </a> \
        </li> \
        <li data-theme='g'> \
            <a href='#FaqPage' data-transition='slide'> \
                <img src='Imagenes/ico_menu_help.png' class='ui-li-icon'>{10} \
            </a> \
        </li> \
        <li id='menu_logOff' data-theme='g'> \
            <a href='#LoginPage' data-transition='slide'> \
                <img src='Imagenes/ico_menu_logoff.png' class='ui-li-icon'>{11} \
            </a> \
        </li> \
        <li id='menu_logIn' data-theme='g'> \
            <a href='#LoginPage' data-transition='slide'> \
                <img src='Imagenes/ico_menu_signin.png' class='ui-li-icon'>{12} \
            </a> \
        </li> \
    </ul>";

text = app.util.I18n.format(
    text,
    app.util.I18n.translate('menu_Home'),
    app.util.I18n.translate('menu_nextInjection'),
    app.util.I18n.translate('menu_recordedInjection'),
    app.util.I18n.translate('menu_charts'),
    app.util.I18n.translate('menu_messages'),
    app.util.I18n.translate('menu_library'),
    app.util.I18n.translate('menu_surveys'),
    app.util.I18n.translate('menu_myProfile'),
    app.util.I18n.translate('menu_dailyInjection'),
    app.util.I18n.translate('menu_settings'),
    app.util.I18n.translate('menu_faq'),
    app.util.I18n.translate('menu_logoff'),
    app.util.I18n.translate('menu_logIn')
);
$(".logoHead").on("click", function(){ $.mobile.changePage("#HomePage2", {changeHash: true}); });
$("[name='menu']").html(text);

// Log off
$("[name='menu'] #menu_logOff a").click(function(event) {
    showMenuOptionsForLoggedUser(false);
    localStorage.setItem("user", '');
    localStorage.setItem("pass", '');
});
showMenuOptionsForLoggedUser(false);

// Actualizamos titulo del menu
updateMenuTitle();
```

}

Transitions are made with jquerymobile, for example this is the panel3 example, I have reviewed that panelId's are no repeated between pages...:

```
    <!-- MY PROFILE -->
<div data-role="page" data-control-title="MyProfile" id="MyProfilePage">
    <div data-role="panel" id="panel3" data-position="left" data-display="reveal" data-theme="f" name="menu">
    </div>
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" id="header" style="z-index: 100">
        <a id="myProfile_btnDone" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-right" data-corners="false">
            Done
        </a>
        <a id="menuLateral" data-controltype="panelbutton" data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="#panel3" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left" data-corners="false">
        </a>
        <h5 class="logoHead"></h5>
    </div>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div data-role="content" style="padding: 0px">
        <div data-role="popup" name="popup_progress">
            <p style="padding: 1em;">
                <img src="css/images/progress.gif" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div data-controltype="htmlblock">
            <div id="myProfile_lblTitle" class="cab">
                Define your profile
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textinput" class="margenes-laterales">
            <label id="myProfile_lblFirstName" for="myProfile_txtFirstName">
                First Name
            </label>
            <input name="" id="myProfile_txtFirstName" placeholder="" value="" type="text" data-mini="true" maxlength="80" />
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textinput" class="margenes-laterales">
            <label id="myProfile_lblLastName" for="myProfile_txtLastName">
                Last Name
            </label>
            <input name="" id="myProfile_txtLastName" placeholder="" value="" type="text" data-mini="true" maxlength="80" />
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="dateinput" class="margenes-laterales">
            <label id="myProfile_lblBirthDate" for="myProfile_dateBirthDay">
                Birth date
            </label>
            <input data-mini="true" class="margenes-laterales" name="" id="myProfile_dateBirthDay" placeholder="" value="" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-theme="e" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "dateFormat": "YYYY/mm/dd", "centerHoriz": true, "useModal": "true"}'/>
        </div>
        <div data-controltype="htmlblock" class="margenes-laterales">
            <div class="flex-container">
                <div id="myProfile_lblHeight" class="flex-item itemLabelProfile">
                    Height
                </div>
                <div class="flex-item itemHeightWeight">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textinput">
                        <input name="" id="myProfile_txtAltura" placeholder="000.00" value="" type="number" data-mini="true" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-item itemUnitsProfile">
                    <div id="myProfile_radioAltura" data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="radiobuttons">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
                            <input id="radioFt" name="radioHeight" value="ft" data-theme="a" type="radio" />
                            <label for="radioFt">
                                ft
                            </label>
                            <input id="radioCm" name="radioHeight" value="cm" data-theme="a" type="radio" />
                            <label for="radioCm">
                                cm
                            </label>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-container">
                <div id="myProfile_lblWeight" class="flex-item itemLabelProfile">
                    Weight
                </div>
                <div class="flex-item itemHeightWeight">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textinput">
                        <input name="" id="myProfile_txtPeso" placeholder="000.00" value="" type="number" data-mini="true" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-item itemUnitsProfile">
                    <div id="myProfile_radioPeso" data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="radiobuttons">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
                            <input id="radioLb" name="radioWeight" value="lb" data-theme="a" type="radio" />
                            <label for="radioLb">
                                lb
                            </label>
                            <input id="radioKg" name="radioWeight" value="kg" data-theme="a" type="radio" />
                            <label for="radioKg">
                                kg
                            </label>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Perharps 12 panels is too much heavy? Is could be a better solution to create and destroy every panel in 'onbeforeshow' to reduce the amount of memory usage?

Comment: Are you sure the same panel isn't being added multiple times to same page? If you're willing to upgrade to JQM 1.4, you will be able to use one global panel for all pages (external panel).

Comment: Sure, the same panel is created 12 times, but is it a problem? Perhaps transition history is allocating too much memory?

Comment: Upgrade to 1.4 in not currently on my options. Perhaps is there some problem not closing panels when navigate from the links inside them? Sometimes some pages appear with the menu opened and blocked....

Comment: Then close panel once navigated away, use `pagebeforechange` to close active panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code did the trick:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
  $("[data-role=panel] a").on("click", function () {
    if($(this).attr("href") == "#"+$.mobile.activePage[0].id) {
      $("[data-role=panel]").panel("close");
    }
  });
});
```

Extracted from: [Closing jQuery Mobile Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478094/closing-jquery-mobile-panel)